# R Plotly: Adding a reference legend

Tags: r, legend, plotly

I have a bubble plot of varying diameters and want a legend to show how the markers (which can be sized arbitrarily with `sizeref`) relate to the real data. For example, suppose my data that is sizing the markers is in the range [0,12]. I want to include a legend that shows what a marker of size "12" and size "6" look like, so the user can better understand what the size of the markers mean.

```
test <- data.frame(matrix(NA, ncol=3, nrow=14))
colnames(test) <- c("Group", "Numbers", "Days")
loop<- 1
for(i in 1:7){
    test[i,] <- c(1, i, loop)
    loop <- loop * 1.5
}
loop <- 1
for(i in 1:7){
    test[i+7,] <- c(2, i, loop)
    loop <- loop * 1.3
}
plot_ly(test, x=Group, y=Numbers, size=Days, mode="markers")
```

[image]

Comment: Look into the `hoverinfo` argument of the `plot_ly` function. It doesn't exactly select distinct bubbles but it could be a good start.